# Prevent UWP WebView from loading images etc

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to show a webpage without loading anything but the page itself. Not even CSS or JavaScript pages. I want the WebView to make only one web request - to get the page from the url I provide it. Nothing else.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: what's mean of `WebView to make only one web request - to get the page from the url`.?

Comment: You just can't. This limited crap control (as the entire UWP) does not allow you to monitor and filter the requests it make to load the page.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I want there to be only one request from my computer to/from the web - to get the html at someUrl.com. And then I want that html shown on the WebView.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It seems he wants to "show" the content not just download it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT How to display html in RichTextBlock without parsing every single element?

Comment: Sorry @MehrzadChehraz, I miss understand op's requirement.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Thanks for the help. I guess your answer is correct: It can't be done. I wonder if the fact that MS is moving away from Edge will be for the better in this respect.

Comment: @ispiro It will be good if they do so, not so sure if they allow this as they probably keep the same api contract and make the control as limited (and useless) as possible.

Comment: Use the WebResourceRequested event to block all but the first request. (Return 404 or whatever you like for the other requests.)